# Adobe PDF JavaScript String Extraction

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, adobe, extract

I am currently attempting to Automate an Action Wizard script where I can pull out names as strings and then use those strings to name the file and re-save it as “Last-Name, First Name - Name of Document”.  I am specifically having trouble with the string extraction and file name creation.

Essentially, let’s say the name is

John Smith

The only differentiator is it’s font, which is different from the rest of the document.  I need to pull that name from the document and then re-save it as the file name as “Smith, John - Name of Document”.  If it helps at all, the page where the information needs to be extracted is always on a certain page, the same in each document. Any help would be incredibly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, Acrobat JavaScript can't get at the font used for a certain word. However, if the bounding box of the name is different enough from the rest of the document, that might help. Also if the name is always at the same coordinates, you can find the name that way. Can you post a sample document somplace?

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! Unfortunately, the information is confidential, I was trying to find a way to post it here but I couldn't redact everything.  It is, however, in the same location on almost every document.  Is there a way to say something like                                  
    if(exists string in these coordinates) {extract string} else { output "no name")                                                                                                          sorry I realize this has been incredibly crude, thank you so much for your help

Comment: You also tagged your question [tag:java]. Does that mean that you alternatively also accept a Java solution?

Comment: Yes, I’m using action wizard in adobe pdf pro so only Java is accepted.

Comment: "Is there a way to say something like if(exists string in these coordinates) {extract string} else { output "no name")"

Sort of...Acrobat JavaScript will let you iterate over each word on a given page and then discover it's location (a bounding box). With that information, you can determine if the word exists inside the rectangle that the name occurs in. Warning...it won't be fast.

Comment: That could work, even if it’s not fast it can still help. Also there’s not a lot of text on the page itself